# Storing SQLite database in IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, php, sqlite, offline, indexeddb

I have a pretty simple question, but I'm having an incredibly hard time finding an answer. I'd like to allow my users to cache small SQLite databases that I host on my server, locally using IndexedDB. An all javascript solution would be ideal, but a combination of PHP and JS is also acceptable. I've written a PHP script that takes the SQLite db and returns the data in a JSON format, but I'm kind of at a loss from there.

Answer (score 1):

You are own right track, by thinking of using IndexedDB. As you are saying, your php script is ready for making your data in JSON format. You can directly store this data now as it is in browser using IndexedDB API. For starting these links can be helpful -https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB and http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/

But do remember indexedDB is only supported in modern browsers and Safari(mobile and desktop) does not support indexedDB. For supporting safari, you can use this [IndexedDB Shim.](http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/)